# Why Net | Node.js TcpServer maxConnection should not be used in child process?

Tags: javascript, node.js

From he Node.js [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_maxconnections):

> **server.maxConnections**
>
> Added in: v0.2.0
>
> - `<integer>`
>
> Set this property to reject connections when the server's connection count gets high.
>
> It is not recommended to use this option once a socket has been sent to a child with `child_process.fork()`.

Comment: Part of your question seems like it's a quote. Please mark it as such by using `>` in front of its text, and link to what you're quoting. Looks like it's [this](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_maxconnections).

Comment: What your title asks is not what the documentation says not to do.

Comment: I think what's going on is that when you pass a connection to a child process, then the maxConnections setting may no longer be accurate.  It doesn't say not to use it in a child_process - it says not to use it (in the parent) once you're passing sockets to a child_process.